# Sending a JSON message using Java

Tags: java, json, http-post

I'm triying to send this json message:

> {"ruido_exterior":0,"co2_exterior":0,"humedad_interior":0,"ruido_interior":0,"temperatura_exterior":0,"co_interior":0,"co2_interior":0,"co_exterior":0,"temperatura_interior":0,"pm_25":8,"pm_10":10,"humedad_exterior":0,"timestamp":1494978084000}

**Code**

```
public static void sendRequestPostRenam(JSONObject json) throws IOException, JSONException {

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        try {

            URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder(Config.urlJSON).addParameter("access-token", Config.renamToken);

            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(builder.build());
            StringEntity params = new StringEntity(json.toString());

            request.setEntity(params);

            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

            //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="PRUBEAS DEBUG">
            String content = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            Log.debug(content);
            //</editor-fold>

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            Log.debug("[STATUS:" + statusCode + "]");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.debug(ex.toString());
        } finally {
            httpClient.close();
        }
    }
```

The output of **content** is:

> {"status":"error","info":{"timestamp":["Timestamp no puede estar vacío."]},"timestamp":1495068046}

The message says "Timestamp can't be empty" but in the varibale "**params**" the timestamp value is contained. The point it looks like the request object doesn't have this json values.

EDIT 1:

I'm going to explain what I need to do. I have to send some data to an API via Json. It has access-token authentification and if I use curl I don't have any problem sending the data:

> curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"pm25": 35, "timestamp": 147805158}' https://api.com/data/insert?access-token={Yoq3UGQqDKP4D1L3Y6xIYp-Lb6fyvavpF3Lm-8cD}

As a result of the last command the answer is:

> {"status":"ok","info":[],"timestamp":1495072199}

Anything help will be really apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to comment yet on your post, so pasting query as an answer here.

If I haven't miss anything then content you are printing depends upon the handling and business logic defined in remote service you are calling. You should provide more details regarding your remote service.

Anyways you could try adding header of content type in you request HttpPost object.
    `request.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have to send some data to an API. If I use curl for this I get a status:ok answer. This is the comand:

curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"pm25": 35, "timestamp": 147805158}' https://url.com/insert?access-token={Yoq3UGQqDKP4D1L3Y6xIYp-Lb6fyvavpF3Lm-8cD}

Comment: Yes I used the header but now i'm getting an internal server error 500.
Now i'm going to use the header to try to emulate the curl message but it looks like it's not work at all but I couln't find why